# python set comprehension for loop unexpected return

Tags: python, for-loop, set, list-comprehension

i'm trying to do an excercise from pynative.
I did it using for loop and using the set method difference_update.
Now i want to do the for loop using comprehension but i don't get it right, the set returns empty
The last one is the one giving me hard times.
The expected output should be `{10, 30}` but it returns `{None}`

> Update the first set with items that don’t exist in the second set
> Given two Python sets, write a Python program to update the first set with
> items that exist only in the first set and not in the second set.

```
set1 = {10, 20, 30}
set2 = {20, 40, 50}
for i in set2:
    if i in set1:
        set1.remove(i)
print(set1)

set11 = {10, 20, 30}
set21 = {20, 40, 50}
set11.difference_update(set21)
print(set11)

THIS IS THE ONE
set12 = {10, 20, 30}
set22 = {20, 40, 50}
set12 = {set12.remove(x) for x in set22 if x in set12}
print(set12)
```

Comment: You are making a set that contains the result of `remove`, which returns `None`. If you really want a comprehension, you could write `set12 = {x for x in set12 if x not in set22}`

Comment: "Now i want to do the for loop using comprehension but i don't get it right," a set comprehension *is not a for-loop*, you are trying to use your comprehension for *side-effects*, i.e. `set12.remove(x)`, but that isn't what comprehensions are for, they are for functional, mapping/filtering operations. Fundamentally, you shouldn't use comprehensions to *mutate* (i.e. update) objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the below line of code :

```py
set12 = {set12.remove(x) for x in set22 if x in set12}
```

you first modify the set12 and remove extra element then replace set 12.

use this code in the last line

```py
setppp = {set12.remove(x) for x in set22 if x in set12}
print(set12)
```